# Most optimal way to load data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to load data in 15 min intervals for up to 6 months of data for each series.  The number of series could range from 2 to 20.

So I tried loading a simple array of values `[28, 83, 13, 30, ...]` and setting the `plotOptions` to start at a `00:00` with `15 min interval` so the `xAxis` is dynamically generated.  Works well enough.

I also need to include annotations which can happen at anytime like `13:19` outside the 15 min interval.

Does that mean I need to load an array of `[x, y]` pairs such as `[['00:00', 28], ['00:15', 83], ['00:30', 13], ['00:45', 30], ...]` in order for annotations at random times to be able to plot?

Is the performance slower loading an array of `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], ...]` vs `[y1, y2, y3, ...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data format you provide to the chart does not affect the ability to add annotations. The chart points will still have the same property structure.

You can easily compare performance for different data formats:

```
console.time('Create chart');

Highcharts.chart('container', {...});

console.timeEnd('Create chart')
```

Tests for **17280** points per series (**4** series):

- An array of numerical values: **496.66ms - 664.18ms**

  Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9xs20mrf/
- An array of arrays with 2 values: **444.14ms - 610.68ms**

  Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0n18c9L6/
- An array of objects (without turbo mode): **496.46ms - 726.66ms**

  Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b3ntosd2/

As you can see the differences are relatively small. The best result (the second test), probably results from the fact that the chart does not have to calculate the x values.